# Re-indexing large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

Hello I have played with Pandas a little bit but cannot seem to find the combination of code that will allow me to arrange a dataframe I have with new multi-indexes

[Picture of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPxoF.png)

is what it looks like when I run `dataNYSE.set_index([dataNYSE.columns[0]])` The picture is how I would like to rearrange it if it makes sense. I basically want to get the tickers which are currently in the row of NaN above Date then use the date as a series to each ticker so there are two indices on the left and then that should bring down all of the 18k columns down a bit though it will make the row number go up a lot I'd rather have them in this organization.

Comment: Are you looking to `df = df.T.set_index(df.columns[0], append=True)`?

Comment: Sadly not thank you though

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to help you if do a more detailed explanation of what you want. Please edit your question to include your expected output as a text-based table in a code block (not an image). And you could also explain why the suggestion is not what you need, so we can all understand better.

Comment: You should show more of how you have tried to solve this, so we can see exactly which step is causing you problems. For example, include any tracebacks you might get.

Comment: None of what I tried will turn a row into a column I'm stuck at step one essentially everything I have found has been for setting two columns as indices. I was told on a Discord that melt will do what I want but from the sounds of it a function with all of the tickers in a list would need to be made to pull it off.